# Python comparing two 3 dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

I have two numpy arrays:

```
A.shape = (nA,x,y)
```

and

```
B.shape = (nB,x,y).
```

I want to find all subarrays such that

```
A(i,:,:) == B(j,:,:).
```

I know I can write a double for loop and use

```
np.array_equal(A(i,:,:),B(j,:,:)
```

However, is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to loop through one of the arrays, since you wouldn't find any additional unique subarrays after that, and you can do this with a simple list comprehension.

```
subarrays = [x for x in A if x in B]
```

If you only want the indices instead of storing the whole subarray, you can do:

```
indices = [x[0] for x in enumerate(A) if x[1] in B]
```

Comment: Is there a way using the list comprehension to store the indices of the matches instead of the actual data?

Comment: Yep! Just edited my answer with how to do that, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing Steven Rouk's solution, here is a method to get the indices for the subarrays that are equal:

```
indicesForMatches = [(i,j) for i,subArrayOfA in enumerate(A) for j,subArrayOfB in enumerate(B) if np.array_equal(subArrayOfA,subArrayOfB)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
mask = ((A[:,None,:,:] == B).all(2)).all(2)
A_idx,B_idx = np.where(mask)
```

You can use [`reshaping`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to avoid double `.all()` usages and get the mask, like so -

```
mask = (A.reshape(A.shape[0],1,-1) == B.reshape(B.shape[0],-1)).all(-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: # Setup input arrays and force some indices to be same between A and B
    ...: nA = 4 
    ...: nB = 5
    ...: x = 3
    ...: y = 2
    ...: 
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(nA,x,y))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(nB,x,y))
    ...: 
    ...: A[2,:,:] = B[1,:,:]
    ...: A[3,:,:] = B[4,:,:]
    ...: 

In [42]: mask = ((A[:,None,:,:] == B).all(2)).all(2)
    ...: A_idx,B_idx = np.where(mask)
    ...: 

In [43]: A_idx, B_idx
Out[43]: (array([2, 3]), array([1, 4]))

In [44]: mask = (A.reshape(A.shape[0],1,-1) == B.reshape(B.shape[0],-1)).all(-1)
    ...: A_idx,B_idx = np.where(mask)
    ...: 

In [45]: A_idx, B_idx
Out[45]: (array([2, 3]), array([1, 4]))
```